When I make my LWC SSR @api no longer works?
I am a part of the Experience Delivery pilot and I'm hitting an issue where my binding of @api is no longer working once the page renders.
Simple example is the following:
foo.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class Foo extends LightningElement {
    @api bar;

    /* code that sets bar */
}

foo.html
<template>
    <div>{bar}</div>
</template>

js-meta.xml
...
<capabilities>
    <capability>lightning__ServerRenderable</capability>
</capabilities>
...

The component doesn't render the {bar} any longer.

This is due to you utilizing lightning__ServerRenderable as your capability when you actually want to use lightning__ServerRenderableWithHydration. The former will only render your content on the server and LWC will not hook up your component for client-side hydration and thus any of your binding or interactivity will not occur.
